# Unity:Multiplayer Transformation lagging

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am building a multiplayer game in unity.Currently facing an issue ,the players transformation lags in the other device it is connected too but the transformation is fine in its own device.Plus it also does not show the player transformation animation like walking etc.

**NetworkTransform of Player**
[image: NetworkTransform of Player]

Answer (score 1):

You can increase [network send rate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-sendRate.html) to avoid lag in movement. Currently it is set to 9 (as your image depicted) while for animation on network please see [Network animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkAnimator.html).

> The NetworkAnimator is used to synchronize animations across the
>   network{[tut here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsZiHe8yN9A)}.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i don't use NetworkTransition i used synchonize position and update each Client.

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.SyncVarAttribute.html
```

Second i reference use NetworkAnimator to solve animation synchonize issue:

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkAnimator.html
```